# if statement always display true even the input is false

Tags: php, registration

```
<?php

    include("connection2.php");     

    if(!empty($_POST['lrn'])  && !empty($_POST['password'])){

        $lrn = $_POST['lrn'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        $check = "SELECT * from studentinf where LRN = '".$lrn."'";
        $qry = mysql_query($check);
        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($qry); 
        $check2 = "SELECT * from studentinf where Password = '".$pass."'";
        $qry2 = mysql_query($check2);
        $num_rows2 = mysql_num_rows($qry2); 

        if($num_rows > 0){
            echo "<center>LRN is valid</center> ";
        }

        else 
            echo "<font color='#FF0000'><center>Your LRN is Invalid. <br>Please Contact your Web   Administrator for your LRN.</center></font>";


        if($num_rows2 != "")
        {
            echo "account already registered";            
        }

        else if ($num_rows2 == "")
        {
            echo "account not yet registered";
            $query = "UPDATE studentinf SET Password = '$pass' where LRN = '$lrn'";
            mysql_query($query);

            echo "Thank You for Registration.";
            echo '<br><a href="studentlogin.php">Click Here</a> to login your account.';
        }
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: heresmycodefixitformeplzthanks. Try reducing your problem and at least explaining which line is causing the error.

Comment: There are 4 `if` statements in there, which ones are you having trouble with?

Comment: Well.. at least it's hackable.

Comment: Seeing your code i saw the password is not hashed bad idea ,also 
----------

>[**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: ^ You guys are awesome.

Comment: Do you really allow the user to change the password without knowing the old password, just because they give a valid LRN?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing right about which `if` statement you mean, try replacing:

```
if($num_rows2 != "")
{
  echo "account already registered";
}
else
if ($num_rows2 == "")
{
  // ...
}
```

with:

```
if ($num_rows2 > 0)
{
  echo "account already registered";
}
else
{
  // ...
}
```

`$num_rows2` is numeric; compare it against a number, not a string.